# ios 5 - Code to Reflect on Storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard

When you create an interface with Storyboard (OR normal IB) the code is generated at compile time for the app. In other words, it does not update the file of the ViewController it is linked to.

Is there a setting that allows for this?
For me I would see that as a great learning tool.

Like if I put a button on a certain place in a UIView, what would that look like in code?

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such setting. XIB's and Storyboards are stored as XML files, and rendered into UI at runtime. On the other hand, when you create UI programmatically you write your code in Objective C using Cocoa Touch classes. There is no direct way to convert the XML into Objective C during development.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, would have been nice though:-)